# Securing API using subscription keys

Tags: azure-api-management

This is a follow-up to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57111256/37759) about how to secure subscription keys when calling API from client-side code.

I read through [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions#what-are-subscriptions) that states: "By publishing APIs through API Management, you can easily secure API access using subscription keys." However, if you have a client-side app that wants to call API, the subscription keys will be visible to anyone who inspects the HTTP request in browser web tools.

Now anyone can take your subscription keys and make API calls on your behalf.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I would suggest some form of query channelling so only queries that come from a whitelist of sources are allowed to test the key value. For example on HTTP headers you can add [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) `CSP`  headers (amongst others) to ensure only requests from `example-website-yes.com` can access your content

Answer (score 2):

If you use HTTP**S**, the headers are encrypted.

> the universe exists for only 13.7 billion years, but we will need 9.1732631 followed by 50 zeros years to crack a 256-bit SSL Certificate.
> (from https://www.ssldragon.com/blog/cracking-ssl/)

However, the key can always leak on the consumer side somehow, by employees who leak it, or store it badly.

To prevent that, it is advised to implement OAuth in APIM.

Comment: hi @Jelle can we use the same OAuth as we used in the Frontend app SSO?